# Optimizing OpenGL ES 2.0 Drawing for Android

Tags: java, android, optimization, opengl-es, drawing

Platform: Android
Version: 2.2 and above
Acceleration: OpenGL ES 2.0
Language: Java
IDE: ADT - Eclipse

I am trying to utilize OpenGL ES 2.0 to rapidly accelerate the drawing of 2D Sprites for a game I'm creating, however I am not getting the speed I need from OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android. Below is my code related that is related to drawing in OpenGL. When using the profiler most of the time per frame is being taken up by the Draw method.

Also, because of the nature of the game CreateModelMatrix() has be be called each frame before drawing because the objects are constantly moving and rotating.

How can I optimize the Draw method to make it more effecient?

```
void Create(float[] ModelData, float[] CoordData)
    {
        //Count Verts
        Verts = ModelData.length / 3;

        //Create Buffer outside Java VM
        FloatBuffer ModelBuffer;
        ModelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ModelData.length* BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        ModelBuffer.put(ModelData).position(0);
        FloatBuffer CoordBuffer;
        CoordBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(CoordData.length* BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        CoordBuffer.put(CoordData).position(0);

        //Create OpenGL Buffer
        final int buffers[] = new int[2];
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2,buffers,0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ModelBuffer.capacity() * 4, ModelBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CoordBuffer.capacity() * 4, CoordBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        VertHandle = buffers[0];
        FrameHandle.add( buffers[1] );
        //Set empty for Garbage Collection
        ModelBuffer.limit(0);
        ModelBuffer = null;
        CoordBuffer.limit(0);
        CoordBuffer = null;

        ModelMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(ModelMatrix, 0);
        //ModelMatrix[3] = 0.5f;
    }
void CreateModelMatrix() {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(ModelMatrix, 0);    
        Matrix.translateM(ModelMatrix,0,x,y,0.0f);
        Matrix.rotateM(ModelMatrix, 0, rot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Matrix.translateM(ModelMatrix,0,-this.OriginX,-this.OriginY,0.0f);
    }
void Draw() 
    {
        //final int stride = (POSITION_DATA_SIZE + NORMAL_DATA_SIZE + TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE) * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

        // Pass in the position information
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertHandle);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, POSITION_DATA_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, POSITION_DATA_SIZE * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, 0);

        // Pass in the texture information
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, FrameHandle.get((int)Frame));
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, 0);

        // Clear the currently bound buffer (so future OpenGL calls do not use this buffer).
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        //Pass the Model Matrix
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMMatrixHandle, 1, false, ModelMatrix, 0);

        //Set Texturing
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

        // Draw the cubes.
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, Verts);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be drawing a lot of the same object, a simple thing you can do is avoid making redundant calls.

For example, in [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/), I recently determined that I could cut the CPU (not GPU) time in half by splitting out some of the setup code.  If the values passed to functions like `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, `glVertexAttribPointer`, and `glActiveTexture` are the same for a series of objects, you want to set those values once and then draw all the objects you can.

In my case objects really only came in two flavors (textured and non-textured), so a bunch of calls went from being issued a hundred times per frame to twice per frame.

See [this bit of code](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/BasicAlignedRect.java#171) for a specific example.  `sDrawPrepared` is a sanity check I use to make sure that I only call draw when the class is prepared.  (It doesn't check for all possible errors, but if you look at `onDrawFrame()` you'll see it's just not that complicated a game.)